# How to build an oscillator with an envelope on its frequency/pitch in Audiokit?

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I am new to Audiokit and I try to build a synth where I can route an AD-Envelope to different parameters, like frequency of an oscillator etc.
To me it seems that it only is possible to solve this on a DSP level. 
[I found out](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/audiokit/Ukz4A0JwvAc) that the AKxxxOscillatorBanks are ADSR'ing the volume and I might have to use this part of code to "apply this only to the pitch".

So it seems that I just have to script a "new bank type that does the ADSR over other kinds of parameters". As I want to have full controll over the frequency and only need a monophonic oscillator I would onyl need to implement the ADSR envelope into a new version of AKMorphingOscillator, but I don't know where to start.

I think I would have to edit the

```
void run(int frameCount, float* outL, float* outR)
```

from AKMorphingOscillatorBankDSPKernel.hpp and there it looks like the ADSR works in the for-loop like

```
sp_adsr_compute(kernel->sp, adsr, &internalGate, &amp);
sp_oscmorph_compute(kernel->sp, osc, nil, &x);
```

But thats where my knowledge stops. Any help would be appreciated. thnx!

edit: still on it. maybe the AKOperationGenerator could also be the right direction, like in [this example](http://audiokit.io/playgrounds/Synthesis/Filter%20Envelope/).

Comment: Seems that this would be too complicated or the complete wrong direction. I stopped this approch and went on with this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49140013/swift-audiokit-how-to-build-an-vco-whos-pitch-is-controlled-by-an-ar-envelope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that this would be too complicated or the complete wrong direction. I stopped this approch and went on with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49140013/swift-audiokit-how-to-build-an-vco-whos-pitch-is-controlled-by-an-ar-envelope).